# Print pattern in first file when there is a match on second file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have these to files.

file1.txt

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

file2.txt

```
A 1
B 2
D 3
```

My desired out put is as follows:

```
A
B
D
```

I tried using `grep -Ff file1.txt file2.txt` but the result is

```
A 1
B 2
D 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Job for `join`:

```
join -o 1.1 f1.txt f2.txt
```

by default `join` joins on the whitespace delimited first field of the files. `-o 1.1` specifies the output, we are only interested in the first field of the first file.

If the files are not sorted, you ned to `sort` them first:

```
join -o 1.1 <(sort f1.txt) <(sort f2.txt)
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat f1.txt                    
A
B
C
D
E

$ cat f2.txt                    
A 1
B 2
D 3

$ join -o 1.1 f1.txt f2.txt 
A
B
D
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But I get this error:
join: file 2 is not in sorted order
join: file 1 is not in sorted order

Comment: @Neil Check my edits..

Comment: I still got an error:
join: file 2 is not in sorted order

Comment: @Neil Please post your original file content..

Answer (score 0):

Though `join` is much easier than this one, but you can also try this one using `awk`,

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1}NR!=FNR && $1 in a{print a[$1]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

**Demo**

```
$ cat file1.txt                    
A
B
C
D
E

$ cat file2.txt                    
A 1
B 2
D 3

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1}NR!=FNR && $1 in a{print a[$1]}' file1.txt file2.txt
A
B
D
```

Comment: Hi Rahul. It gives blank output. :)

Comment: are you sure you are running exact command ? and also make sure file order. `file1` and `file2`